# Div height at 100% either not tall enough or too tall

Tags: html, css

I thought I was getting the hang of this, then I ran into a hitch I cannot figure out.

If I have the wrapper height set to auto, it comes down to the bottom of the content and stops, if the content is not as tall as the window, you see the background behind it. If I have the wrapper set to 100 percent then it does not work.

When the screen is maximized, the page is taller than the window height, and forces the page to scroll unnecessarily.

When the window is smaller, the background crawls up behind the content. I don't want the page to scroll when it doesn't need to, and when the window is shrunk I want the background of the wrapper to still cover the content. How do I fix this?

### Edit

```
<div id="xwraper">
<div id="wraper">

    <br class="cl cr" /> 
    <div id="imgholder">
        <div class="slider">
                            <ul>
                                <li rel="1">
                                    <img src="id_tags_1.png" width="510" height="340" alt="&nbsp;" />
                                    <h4>&nbsp;</h4>
                                </li>
                                <li rel="2">

                                    <img src="id_tags_2.png" width="510" height="340" alt="&nbsp;" />
                                    <h4>&nbsp;</h4>
                                </li>
                                <li rel="3">
                                    <img src="id_tags_3.png" width="510" height="340" alt="&nbsp;" />
                                    <h4>&nbsp;</h4>
                                </li>
                                <li rel="4">
                                    <img src="id_tags_4.png" width="510" height="340" alt="&nbsp;" />

                                    <h4>&nbsp;</h4>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <div class="clear controls">
                                <img src="../../img/white-arrow-left.png" width="10" height="13" alt="&lt;" class="prev" />
                                <span class="pages">
                                    <img src="../../img/blank.gif" width="13" height="14" alt="&nbsp;" class="number hide selected 1" />
                                    <img src="../../img/blank.gif" width="13" height="14" alt="&nbsp;" class="number hide 2" />
                                    <img src="../../img/blank.gif" width="13" height="14" alt="&nbsp;" class="number hide 3" />

                                    <img src="../../img/blank.gif" width="13" height="14" alt="&nbsp;" class="number hide 4" />
                                </span>
                                <img src="../../img/white-arrow-right.png" width="10" height="13" alt="&gt;" class="next" />
                            </div>
                        </div>        </div>
    <div id="desc">
        <p>Identification Tags are a versatile, cost effective way to get your marketing message out. Used by travelers, sports teams, schools, health clubs, athletes and organizations, these tags are durable and each comes with it's own clear lanyard.</p>  
        <p>The back of each tag can be written on or we'll print another message on them for you. Choose one of our standard sizes, or we'll work with your custom size and shape. Please call Customer Service for pricing on custom shapes and sizes.</p>

        <ul>
            <li class="ulhead center">Product Specific Info.</li>
            <li class="ulhead">Stock</li>
            <li>Printed on durable .020&rdquo; thick plastic</li>
            <li class="ulhead">Color</li>
            <li>Neon and metallic colors are not available on Identifcation Tags</li>

            <li class="ulhead">Production Time</li>
            <li>Standard production time is approximately 10 days</li>
            <li class="ulhead">General</li>
            <li>Tags with no imprint are available, write or call for pricing</li>
            <li><a href="../../contact_us.php">Contact us</a> for a quote on custom sizes or shapes</li>

        </ul>
    </div>
    <br class="cl cr" /> 
    <table id="pb">
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr class="bold">

                        <td>&nbsp;</td>  <td>125</td>  <td>250</td>  <td>500</td>  <td>1,000</td>  <td>1,500</td>  
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>

        </tr>
        <tr class="mt1">
            <td>4-Color Process</td>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Each</td>  <td>2.24</td>  <td>1.37</td>  <td>.86</td>  <td>.569</td>  <td>.452</td>  
                    </tr>

                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Black Imprint</td>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr >

                        <td>Each</td>  <td>.48</td>  <td>.30</td>  <td>.23</td>  <td>.156</td>  <td>.124</td>  
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>5A &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br class="cl cr" />
    <h3>ASI 85950 &bull; PPAI 265052 &bull; SAGE 56520<br />All content &copy; 2012 - Blue Frog Printing</h3>

</div>
</div>
```

And the css for the wrappers:

```
#xwraper {
position:absolute;
left:50%;
top:0px;
width:1px;
height:100%;
overflow:visible;
z-index:-3;
}

#wraper {
position:absolute;
left:-450px;
top:0px;
width:900px;
height:100%;
padding-top:110px;
background-color:#FFFFFF;
border-left: solid 5px #003860;
border-right: solid 5px #003860;
z-index:inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set the height property to 100% it assumes the height of its parent element, i.e. element id "xwraper" that is also assuming the height of its parent element, the body tag which by default is the viewport size. (Note how the height adjusts when you open and close the Chrome Dev Tools!) Obviously the value of auto just assumes the smallest height necessary to wrap around the content, as you described.

The reason for the extra scroll height is the bottom margin of the last h3 tag within this element id "wraper". You need to adjust the following CSS rule, from which the problem is stemming:

```
h3 {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:15px;
    width:900px;
    margin:40px 0px 60px 0px; /* INSERT ALARM BELLS */
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
}
```

To resolve the issue you should also change your height properties on xwraper and wraper to `min-height` of 100%. These two things in combination should deliver the look you desire. In summary, you should end up with:

```
#wraper {
    position: absolute;
    left: -450px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 900px;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding-top: 110px;
    background-color: white;
    border-left: solid 5px #003860;
    border-right: solid 5px #003860;
    z-index: inherit;
}

#xwraper {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 0px;
    width: 1px;
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow: visible;
    z-index: -3;
}

#xwraper #wraper > h3 {
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```

Comment: That took care of the background of the wrapper not being long enough, but it still scrolls when it should all fit in the window with out scrolling.  It scrolls as you pointed out due to the padding at the top, but how do i get it to only scroll when needed???  Thanks for your help so far.  I didnt know min-height was a thing.

Comment: That would be because I kept a little bit of margin at the bottom, try change the last rule to `#xwraper #wraper > h3 { margin-bottom: 0; }` if you so desire. Keep in mind it's a fluke the extra 8px is pushing your window to scroll, not every resolution will appear that way; for example my 1366x768 laptop screen just shows an ordinary 2/3 height scrollbar with half a line of whitespace under the copyright notice.

Answer (score 0):

try adding this at the end of the content

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your wrapper is not aligned to the top of the window -- ie it has a top margin or top padding -- it will still be resized to 100% of the window height, but will push past the bottom of the page.

But either way, posting more of your code would help give us some context!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend setting a min-height. I tried using 900px on #xwrapper and it seemed to work quite well.